# How to I run a C# Framework API

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, frameworks

The question may be a bit idiotic, but I can't find the answer on internet or Microsoft tutorials.

The goal of my project is to build an API to has to run locally on a Windows computer. My API mustn't have an interface or things like that, so I deleted every views and other files like bootstrap or jQuery. Then I call it with Unity.

The API works well, but I always run it with Visual Studio 2019. Is there something like a .exe or a command line to start my API ?

Thank you for your answers ! :)

PS : Yeah I know that an API running locally is quite useless, but with Unity it's really complicated to use things like pipes...

Comment: Is this .NET Core?

Comment: @DavidG No it's .Net Framework, the library I use can't run with Core.

Comment: Then you need to run it inside of IIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can host your WebApi application in IIS, so you don't need to run it with Visual Studio.

If you are developing another project, you can ask Visual Studio to run multiple projects during a debugging session. While debuging your unity application, Visual Studio will run your API in the background:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-set-multiple-startup-projects?view=vs-2019

Otherwise, you may self host your asp.net webapi application.
There are official Microsoft tutorials on that:

- For WebAPI 1:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/self-host-a-web-api
- For WebAPI 2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api

Comment: Thank you so much ! The first tutorial had a problem when I tested it but the second was perfect !